# Java Web Start unable to load resource

Tags: java, jboss, java-web-start, wildfly

I am trying out a Simple Java Web Start project based on the [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/index.html). I am using maven to package it as a webapp and deploy it to WildFly 8.1. The full source code is available here

https://github.com/KiranMohan/dynamic-tree-javaws-sample-project

The jnlp file and the deployed jar can be found here

https://github.com/KiranMohan/dynamic-tree-javaws-sample-project/tree/master/dynamic-tree-javaws-webapp/src/main/webapp

The .war file is deployed successfully and the jnlp file is successfully launched from `http://localhost:8080/dynamic-tree-javaws-webapp`. However javaws throws the below error and exits.

```
Unable to load resource: http://localhost:8080/dynamic-tree-javaws-webapp/dynamic-tree-lib.jar
```

The wrapped exception is `FileNotFoundException`.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Actually this seems to be a bug in WildFly 8.1 https://issues.jboss.org/browse/UNDERTOW-253

The workaround suggested in the discussion temporarily resolves the issue.

Comment: Be sure to check the JNLP using JaNeLA, available at my [share drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/#folders/0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0).